# Can someone explain to me why this button doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want to call a function using onclick but it doesn't work and I dont know why.

```
<input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="reset">

<script>
function reset() {
alert();
}
</script>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3mp0869s/1/

Comment: Because the JS is added "onLoad" so reset is undefined. If you put in in head, it works

Comment: I just tested your code in Firefox and it works.(Well I did wrap it in html, head and body tags). What browser are you using?

Maybe try adding     

    <script type="text/javascript" >

Otherwise, I don't suppose you disabled Javascript in your browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works here :
https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/3mp0869s/2/

I believe it was a jsfiddle issue. You need to include inline script function in the html section.

```
<input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="reset">
<script>
    function reset() {
      alert();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you have chosen 'onload' option on jsFiddle, check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mp0869s/3/)

All you need to do is chose 'wrap in the head' option.

Since if you wrap this in an even function scope, it won't have a global scope and it won't be available for the `onclick()` event attribute handler of the `button`.